# Why is the Metro screen randomly coming up for me?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, modern-ui

I log into my computer, see the Metro screen, hit the Desktop icon. I'm now in the Desktop. Sometimes the Metro screen shows itself again after a first login/desktop click, without me doing anything to prompt it to re-display itself. What could be causing such random behavior? I'm running Windows 8, 64-bit.

Comment: Your keyboard is sending wild signals.